# What is wrong with this 2D Array?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, formatting, 2d

I'm using a 2D Array in Java and it's the first time doing so. I'm wondering what is wrong with the array as I'm getting many errors...? (probably a really stupid error)

**Code**

```
    int board[21][21] = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
  {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
  {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1},
  {1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
  {1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}};
```

**Error List**
[Here is a link instead of posting it here since it's a lot of errors](http://pastebin.com/gKgdD5dP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify the size of arrays in the declaration. If you remove your size integers, it will compile. However, you should always place your brackets on your variable's type, not on the variable itself when you declare it as such:

```
int[][] board;
```

rather than:

```
int board[][];
```

If you want to create a blank array with a specific size, then you would do so with the `new` operator:

```
int[][] board = new int[21][21];
```

However, you never specify a size if you define your array though array initialization i.e.

```
int[][] board = {{...}, ...};
```

Comment: Why is putting the brackets on the type better than putting them on the variable?

Comment: It's more clear what the dimension of the variable is. It also prevents you from creating poorly formatted code like the following: `int x, arr[], doubleArr[][], y;` It is also consistent with the construction of the array i.e. `int[] arr = new int[5]` in which the brackets are both on the type not the variable. It's also a Checkstyle violation.

Comment: Because the name of the variable is `board`, not `board[][]` and the type of the variable is `int[][]`, not `int` and in every other case, variables are declared using `type name`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove 21. You should say

`int board[][] = ....`

You have to define dimensions of array when creating them. For example you can say `new int[5]` and create 5 elements long int array. But when you assign this array to variable you say: `int[] arr = new int[5]`. Here `int[]` is a type (int array). It is similar to `int *` in C. You do not have to say how big will be the array when you are defining its type. You just have to say what is its element type and how many dimensions it will have.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you get a compile error for telling the size of your 2D array in the declaration

```
int board[21][21]
```

usually you want to do it this way:

```
int board[][] = {{1,2}{1,3}}
```

This is a 2D array with 2 columns and 2 rows

```
 1 2
 1 3
```

So if you want to a 2D array with 21 rows and 21 columns you should do this:

int board[][] = {{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{],{},{},{},{},{}}

and fill whatever you need in between the inner brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Change first line to `board[][] ={{ all your numbers}}` and all will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is wrong.

```
 int board[][] = new int[][] {{...
```

Answer (score 1):

remove dimensions from declaration:

```
int board[][]
```